# Prove $\sqrt{ z − p} − i \sqrt{p}$ sends exterior of $y ^2 = 4px$ to half-plane $x>0$ (Complex analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, roots, conic-sections, conformal-geometry

How to solve Q4 in Exercises 13.6 of the book "Complex Analysis" by Ian Stewart? Here's the problem:

With a suitable choice of the square root, show that
$f(z) =
\sqrt{
z − p} − i
\sqrt{p}$
maps the exterior of the parabola $y
^2 = 4px$ ($p > 0$) onto the right-hand half-plane
$x > 0$.